# AWS ASG + SNS + Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

looking for some direction.... I need to run some code as EC2 instances come up and terminate from an ASG. I do not have ability to include my script in the AMI itself, since it is a market place appliance. My preference would be to run a Lambda function to execute my code. What I am looking for is a reference implementation preferably with a sample CFT of creating an ASG, creating SNS topic, associating ASG events with the SNS topic, create Lambda to execute as messages post to the topic. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This post was very helpful when I had to do the same: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1VE917Z8J4UDY/Invoking-AWS-Lambda-functions-via-Amazon-SNS

I created the whole thing, including autoscaling group and IAM policies, using Terraform, which worked like a charm.